# github on machine and browser terminal behaviour

Tags: git, shell, github

I am following the tutorial on jlord.us/git-it/challenges/commit_to_it.html and have done whatever it said on my machine and it worked but now I dont see the change reflected in the browser I have added the readme.txt file in the hello-world directory but I dont see the file in the browser. why is that? what am I doing wrong?? even the previous challenges such as git-it and repository I had to do it on both my machine and the browser. seems like I am missing something.

one more thing when I use the command git-it verify on my machine, it doesnt seem to do anything, but when I use it in the browser terminal, then it goes ahead and verifies the thing.
So, what am I missing?

Comment: To see the change in github you have to push your changes to the remote server - github in your case. Have you done that after commit?

Comment: Thanks.
But why doesnt it verify on my machine, while it does so in the browser terminal??

Comment: what browser terminal do you use?

Comment: And what do you mean by 'verify'? If you will be more specific, I'm pretty sure I can explain you what you are missing

Comment: I am using the bash terminal on c9 . the url is https://ide.c9.io/silentarrowz/code-revisions-git

and by verify I mean git-it verify command
when I use it on my machine, it says "ERROR: No active problem. Select a challenge from the menu."

Comment: So actually it's not pretty clear for me the purpose of running your guide both in cloud and on your machine.. And how do you expect your local machine changes be reflected in browser? And what do you mean by "browser"? Where do you expect changes to be reflected?

Comment: Actually, I am not quite sure whether I should be using it only in the browser or in my machine. I was kinda experimenting and trying to figure out what I should be doing.

Comment: Actually, I am not quite sure whether I should be using it only in the browser or in my machine. I was kinda experimenting and trying to figure out what I should be doing.

Comment: Oh, then I would advise you to do it in your local machine and push it to github. Also not sure you have to mess git-it to your git learning..  I think this free course will guide you pretty well https://www.udacity.com/course/how-to-use-git-and-github--ud775

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cloud(you call it browser, I guess) is not connected with your local machine. That's why using git on your local machine does not reflect any changes in the cloud.

My advice for you is to take [this](https://www.udacity.com/course/how-to-use-git-and-github--ud775) free course and learn git just from your local machine without mixes like git-it.